# URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME] tlsv1 unrecognized name (_ssl.c:590)>

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, urllib2

i'm trying to use python2.7--urllib2 to open a website.
  sometimes it shows the error like this:

> URLError: urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME] tlsv1
>   unrecognized name (_ssl.c:590)>

how is it happend? and can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Since you are not giving a specific 2.7. version I'm assuming that the version is not 2.7.9 or later. Builtin support for SNI was only added with version 2.7.9.